# firefox addon depends on user-input data during installation

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, share, firefox-addon-sdk

I am building a firefox add on using the new SDK from firefox. The issue is, my add on scripts depend on a user-input data that the user will provide during installation. I have no idea how to do this. I want to have like a firefox based installation wizard when the add on is being installed. This will configure the scripts. Any idea how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. create a page to ask the user what you need from them
2. open that page on installation if your data isn't set in simple-storage
3. save the user data in simpler storage
4. in the add-on's prefs, create a button that opens the prefs page.

I think the key bit you need to get right is:

- storing the data
- having the add-on check for the data and trigger the pref page if it isn't there